# JSON-LD custom context

Tags: json-ld

I am doing some research about JSON-LD. And I found the for the context is in every example used some public schema sites. Can I use my own ?

From:

```
{
   "@context":{
       "name": "http://schema.org/name"
   }
}
```

To:

```
{
   "@context":{
       "name": "http://my-site.com/name"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely. In most cases you will actually need to do that as you probably won't find vocabularies (that's how those "schemas" are generally called) that cover everything you need. If possible, however, you should try to reuse existing vocabularies as it improves interoperabilty and enables code-reuse.