# Writing my own custom context for JSON-LD

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am attempting to create a JSON-LD context which can be used in a closed / intranet environment with no access to the internet.

To this end I am trying to create my own context as there may be licensing issues copying schema.org wholesale and redistributing it.

I've seen that [creating your own context is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243576/json-ld-custom-context) but I can't see anywhere that explains what the definition of that context should be. Can someone explain what it should be or point me at a description of an existing context as a starting point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official JSON-LD specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#the-context) should tell you everything you need. Don't be scared by the word specification, it's written more like a tutorial than a typical spec.

Comment: I've been there and it is a good reference but all elements in it seem to ultimately go back to schema.org which is what I need to avoid.

Comment: I just noticed this comment in that spec

In JSON-LD documents, contexts may also be specified inline. This has the advantage that documents can be processed even in the absence of a connection to the Web. Ultimately, this is a modeling decision and different use cases may require different handling.

Suddenly it makes sense, the URLs are not meant to be dereferenced to understand the vocabulary.

Comment: Exactly. You can also define your own vocabulary if you prefer (but you prevent reuse and inhibit interoperability by doing so) and host it internally.